# Склоняются ли иностранные фамилии мужчин, заканчивающиеся на букву "а"?

Tags: склонение

Склоняются ли мужские иностранные фамилии, заканчивающаяся на букву "а"?
Например, правильно ли говорить:

- фильм Эмира Кустурицы,
- метод Рунге-Кутты,
- творчество Акиры Куросавы,
- алгоритм Дейкстры,
- песня Никиты Джигурды?

Есть ли по этому поводу какое-нибудь правило в русском языке?

Comment: Только "метод Рунге-Кутты" вызывает у меня глубокие сомнения.

Comment: [Особенности склонения фамилий и личных имен](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482) 13.1.11

Comment: they used to write Ме́тоды Ру́нге — Ку́тта in the past, now it seems to have changed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[нашел на ГРАМОТА.РУ](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482) :

> Все фамилии, кончающиеся на а, которому предшествуют гласные (чаще
>   всего у или и), несклоняемы: *Галуа, Моруа, Делакруа, Моравиа, Эриа,
>   Эредиа, Гулиа*.
>
> Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное а после согласных, склоняются по
>   первому склонению: *Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека —
>   Сенеки* и т.д.; так же склоняются *Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка,
>   Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава* и др.
>   Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются
>   морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется
>   окончание -а.
>
> Среди фамилий с ударным á после согласных есть как морфологически
>   членимые, так и нечленимые, т. е. несклоняемые.
>
> Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения: *Дюма, Тома, Дега,
>   Люка, Ферма, Гамарра, Петипа и др.*
>
> Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков)
>   склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное
>   окончание -а: *Митта — Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой;* сюда относятся:
>   *Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.*